# is using APIs that scrape translations and audio files from google translation website legal?

Tags: internet, terms-of-service, google

Is it legal to use an API that is based on scraping translations and audio files (of the translations) from Google Translation, for personal use? I am not sure of the terms of use of Google Translate concerning that, I did some research but it's still not clear for me whether it's legal or not.

the APIs are:

for the translation: deep-translator: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator

for the audio files: GTTS: https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (used along with playsound)

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate doesn't seem to have a separate ToS from Google overall, but they do offer commercial pricing: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing

The first 500K characters are free. Using more is supposed to be on a subscription basis.

If you are using the API as offered by Google, from your service account, and don't circumvent any restrictions, it should be legal.

Comment: the thing is, am not using their API, i am using someone else's API, that is based on scraping google translate, and that's what am asking about

Comment: Legal questions like specifics. What are their terms of use? The links you've posted are to repos, it doesn't seem like they are offering APIs.